# R: changing all string nominal columns to integers

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I'm planning to use ubRacing of unbalanced package. But this ubRacing only accepts numeric columns. Is there anyway I can convert all the chr columns to numeric through R?

Thanks

'data.frame':   31000 obs. of  22 variables:

```
$ ID            : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ age           : int  56 57 37 40 56 45 59 41 24 25 ...
 $ job           : chr  "housemaid" "services" "services" "admin." ...
 $ marital       : chr  "married" "married" "married" "married" ...
 $ education     : chr  "basic.4y" "high.school" "high.school" "basic.6y" ...
 $ default       : chr  "no" "unknown" "no" "no" ...
 $ housing       : chr  "no" "no" "yes" "no" ...
 $ loan          : chr  "no" "no" "no" "no" ...
 $ contact       : chr  "telephone" "telephone" "telephone" "telephone" ...
 $ month         : chr  "may" "may" "may" "may" ...
 $ day_of_week   : chr  "mon" "mon" "mon" "mon" ...
```

Comment: This would result in all NA values in those columns, according to your example

Comment: How do you want to convert the `job` column which has `housemaid`, `services` etc to `numeric`

Comment: Sorry man!! I haven't seen that till now. It's my roommate who commented and accepted by logging in into my laptop. Yes your answer was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how to `character` columns should be converted to `numeric`.  One possible option would be to convert the `character` class to `factor` and then coerce it to `numeric`.  We loop through the columns of the dataset with `lapply`.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) if(is.character(x)) as.numeric(factor(x))
                                     else (x))
```